# JavaScript doesn't get the country from the input field until i reload the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a Corona Virus case tracker using the disease.sh API but JavaScript doesn't get the country from the input field unless a refresh the page.I tried removing the event listener and adding an onclick attribute but that didn't work, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the endpoint not being made properly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
        </a>

        <p class="display-none">Corona Virus Case Tracker</p>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item" onmouseover="changeThing()" onmouseout="changeThingBack()">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="list-item1" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">More information</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

 

    <input type="text" id="submit-country">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="get cases" />

    <div class="case-results">

    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation-bar-logo {
    width: 240px;
}

img {
  width: 140px;
}

li {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.case-results {
  color: blue;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 250%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

p.display-none {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li:hover a {
  background-position: 100%;
  color: #313131 !important;
  transform: translateX(16px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    p.display-none {
      display: none;
    }
    li[class="nav-item"] {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
let case_results = document.querySelector(".case-results");
let inputField = document.getElementById('submit-country');
let countrySubmitted = inputField.value;
const submit = document.getElementById("submit-button");
const URL = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/';
const lastParams = '?strict=true';
const endpoint = `${URL}${countrySubmitted}${lastParams}`;


/*

Test to change text on hover, to be replaced with icons

function changeThing() {
  document.getElementById('list-item1').innerHTML = 'hduashdas';
}

function changeThingBack() {
  document.getElementById('list-item1').innerHTML = 'Home';
}


*/

//const requestURL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/Moldova?strict=true`;

//Makes a call to the API and retrieves information about a specific country
const getCases = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, { cache: "no-cache" });
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      renderResponse(jsonResponse);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Clears the previous results in the div and displays new ones
function displayCases(event) {
  while(case_results.firstChild) {
    case_results.removeChild(case_results.firstChild)
  }
  getCases();
}

submit.addEventListener('click', displayCases);

const renderResponse = (res) => {
  if (res != null) {
    console.log(res.updated);
    case_results.innerHTML = `cases in ${countrySubmitted} : ${res.cases}` + '<br>';
  } 
};
```

Comment: That's becos you're reading the value from your input before the click on submit. Move the `countrySubmitted = inputField.value;` and the `endPoint` inside `the displayCases` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```js
let case_results = document.querySelector(".case-results");
let inputField = document.getElementById('submit-country');
const submit = document.getElementById("submit-button");


/*

Test to change text on hover, to be replaced with icons

function changeThing() {
  document.getElementById('list-item1').innerHTML = 'hduashdas';
}

function changeThingBack() {
  document.getElementById('list-item1').innerHTML = 'Home';
}


*/

//const requestURL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/Moldova?strict=true`;

//Makes a call to the API and retrieves information about a specific country
const getCases = async () => {
let countrySubmitted = inputField.value;
const URL = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/';
const lastParams = '?strict=true';
const endpoint = `${URL}${countrySubmitted}${lastParams}`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, { cache: "no-cache" });
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      renderResponse(jsonResponse);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Clears the previous results in the div and displays new ones
function displayCases(event) {
  while(case_results.firstChild) {
    case_results.removeChild(case_results.firstChild)
  }
  getCases();
}

submit.addEventListener('click', displayCases);

const renderResponse = (res) => {
if (res != null) {
    case_results.innerHTML = `cases in ${res.country} : ${res.cases}` + '<br>';
  } 
};
```

```css
.navigation-bar-logo {
    width: 240px;
}

img {
  width: 140px;
}

li {
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.case-results {
  color: blue;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
  background-size: 250%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

p.display-none {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li:hover a {
  background-position: 100%;
  color: #313131 !important;
  transform: translateX(16px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    p.display-none {
      display: none;
    }
    li[class="nav-item"] {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <!-- Brand -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="logo">
        </a>

        <p class="display-none">Corona Virus Case Tracker</p>

        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item" onmouseover="changeThing()" onmouseout="changeThingBack()">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="list-item1" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">More information</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

 

    <input type="text" id="submit-country">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="get cases" />

    <div class="case-results">

    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your javascript and confirmed that it works.

```
let case_results = document.querySelector(".case-results");
let inputField = document.getElementById('submit-country');
let countrySubmitted = inputField.value;
const submit = document.getElementById("submit-button");
const URL = 'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/';
const lastParams = '?strict=true';
var endpoint = `${URL}${countrySubmitted}${lastParams}`;


/*

Test to change text on hover, to be replaced with icons

function changeThing() {
  document.getElementById('list-item1').innerHTML = 'hduashdas';
}

function changeThingBack() {
  document.getElementById('list-item1').innerHTML = 'Home';
}


*/

//const requestURL = `https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/Moldova?strict=true`;

//Makes a call to the API and retrieves information about a specific country
const getCases = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, { cache: "no-cache" });
    if (response.ok) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      renderResponse(jsonResponse);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Clears the previous results in the div and displays new ones
function displayCases(event) {
  countrySubmitted = inputField.value;
  endpoint = `${URL}${countrySubmitted}${lastParams}`;
  while(case_results.firstChild) {
    case_results.removeChild(case_results.firstChild)
  }
  getCases();
}

submit.addEventListener('click', displayCases);

const renderResponse = (res) => {
  if (res != null) {
    console.log(res.updated);
    case_results.innerHTML = `cases in ${countrySubmitted} : ${res.cases}` + '<br>';
  } 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of the solutions are working